# Finding the explicit definition of a linear transformation when its matrix representation is known

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\alpha = \{ (0, 2),(2, −1)\} $ and $\beta = \{ (1, 1, 0),(0, 0, −1),(1, 0, 1)\} $ be bases for $\Bbb{R^2}$ and $\Bbb{R^3}$ respectively, and let $S$ be a linear transformation from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}^3$ whose matrix representation in $\alpha,\beta$ is denoted by $[S]_{\alpha,\beta}$. If
$${\begin{bmatrix}
    S
\end{bmatrix}{\alpha},{\beta}}= 
  \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 \end{bmatrix},$$
then what would $S(x, y)$ be like for $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$?

I know the answer is:
$S(x,y) = (y - \frac{3}{2}x, y + \frac{x}{2}, -3x-2y)$.
But I couldn't find a way to reach this result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should define what you mean by $S(x,y)$. We could imagine that $(x,y)$ are the coordinates of a vector… maybe. If so in which basis?

Comment: @Frank_K You should clearly define the terms in your question, using understandable English. One way to do this is to get some linear algebra books and try to mimic their statements. Also, try to make your own opinions by listing some of your ideas. I made some revisions to make your question more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p = (x_1, y_1) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ and $q = (x_2, y_2, z_2) \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Under the linear transformation, $q = T p $  where $T$ is a $3 \times 2$ matrix.

Using the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ bases,

$p = A p' $ and $ q = B q' $

So that $B q' = T A p' $

hence, $q' = B^{-1} T A p' = S p' $

Hence, the required matrix is $T = B S A^{-1} $

Substituting the values given

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
T &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 1 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && - 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 0 \\ 4&& 0 \\ 0 && - 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 2 \\ 2 && -1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 1 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && - 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 0 \\ 4&& 0 \\ 0 && - 4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 \\ 2 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 1 \\ 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && - 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 4 \\ 4&& 8 \\ -8 && 0\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{4} \begin{bmatrix} -6 && 4 \\ 2 && 4 \\ -12 && -8 \end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{3}{2} && 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} && 1 \\ - 3 && - 2 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{split} \end{equation} $

Which confirms the answer that you have.

Answer (score 0):

For a vector $v$ and a basis $\alpha=(u_1,u_2,\dots)$ we write the $\alpha$-coefficients of $v$ in a column vector so that
$$[v]_\alpha=\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\ \vdots}\ \iff\ v=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+\dots$$

The main rule for a linear map $F:V\to W$ is that for all $v\in V$, the value $F(v)$ can be obtained by multiplying with the matrix of $F$ on the left:
$$[F]_{\alpha,\beta}\cdot[v]_\alpha\ =\ [F(v)]_\beta\,.$$
One more important thing is, if $v$ happens to be one of the basis vectors $u_i$, then $[u_i]_\alpha$ has all zero entries except for the $i$th one which is $1$, so, for any matrix $A$, the product $A\cdot[u_i]_\alpha$ is just the $i$th column of $A$.

Can you calculate $S$ based on these information?

Comment: I thought of a calculation like this: $T(2,0)$, $\begin{bmatrix} S\end{bmatrix} = (2,4,0)$ $ \to$ $2(1,1,0) + 4(0,0-1)$. $T(2,0)= (2,2,-4)$.
$T(2,-1)$, $\begin{bmatrix} S\end{bmatrix} = (0,0,-4)$ $ \to$ $(-4)(1,0,1) $. $T(2,-1)= (-4,0,-4)$